# How are TAFTracking and TAFSession used?

Tags: ambient-data-framework

The Ambient Data Framework (ADF) has configurable cookies for Tracking and Session (`TAFTracking` and `TAFSession`, respectively). See details on the [SDL Documentation Center](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-D8BBFEF4-030E-44EB-8416-8FE1BF7C65AF).

**How are these used in Content Delivery and/or product add-ons?** In other words, what happens if you disable them?

I'm looking at the [ADF System Diagram](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-88C6CC86-82D3-4471-B9ED-1DA186EFB354), but can't tell how the cookies work with the ADF Session and Cartridges.

[image: ADF system diagram shows the interaction between web site, ADF client, and Content Service]

Comment: AFAIK - It's mainly used with XPM Footprint ADF Session and Cartridges with smart target